# Folder, folder-relations and files laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relation

I'm trying to create a simple file-manager in Laravel. But I'm struggling with the models and relations between them.

I have 3 models: `Folder`, `FolderRelation` and `Files`

A `Folder` can have many child folders.
A `Folder` can also have only one parent folder.
A `File` belongs to only one folder.

In the folder model I currently have this, but I don't know how I can take use of the pivot table aswell (`FolderRelations`). So how do I fix theese functions to be correct?

```
/**
 * Parent folder
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function parentFolder() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Folder', 'folder_id', 'id');
}

/**
 * Child folders
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function childFolders() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Folder', 'folder_id', 'id');
}
```

I have my tables setup:

#### Folders table

```
+----+--------------------+
| id |        name        |
+----+--------------------+
```

#### FolderRelations table

```
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| folder_id | parent_folder_id | child_folder_id |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

#### Files table

```
+-----------+------------------+------------+
| file_id   | folder_id        | filename   |
+-----------+------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you putting this in a database? What do you see being the main benefit over just using the filesystem itself?

Comment: Actually a good question.. uhm.. I dont really have a good reason that. I thought it may be better to have it stored in a database than just manipulating the filesystem as is. But you don't think there any reason to have this in a database at all?

Comment: I'm not saying that there wouldn't potentially be a benefit, I was just wondering if you'd chosen this route with a specific benefit in mind e.g. if files are related to a user, or you have some sort of complex permission structure. If it's just for the sake of trying to replicate the file system then I don't see then benefit of putting it in a database (happy to hear if there are any others viewpoints though). If you are going to be  going forward with replicating the file  system in your db I would suggest  having a look at  Nested sets https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: I see, well, all user activity is currently logged in my application, and i also already have a user relation in the files model so one can see who uploaded the file.

I'll take a look at nested sets. Thanks! :)

Comment: No worries. As for associating files, I would suggest just having a single files table where you have the whole path for the file in one column.